# Extracting row which are not in other dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have one two dataframes df1 and df2, (say df2 is subset of df1) I have to get rows from df1 which are not df2, I have do it in scala, can any help me out on thhis.

Comment: No, It's not working, I have tried except, I have 10 rows in df2 and 32 rows in df1, when I tried except it is giving all 32 rows and more over columns increased to 18 from 10(orignall df1 and df2 do have 10 columns each).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `except`:

```
df1.except(df2)
```

Comment: No, it's not working, I tried that, I have 10 columns in each.